# detecting specific input from user using BufferedReader

Tags: java, if-statement, bufferedreader, string-comparison

i'm taking user input from

```
String riddle=b.readLine();
riddle1=Integer.parseInt(riddle);
```

and obviously, i'm trying to get the user to answer a riddle.
I tried using the following

```
if(riddle1=="answer")
```

but that doesn't work

Comment: String will be compared using `equals` method not `==`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
riddle.equals("answer");
```

As == doesn't checks whether both strings are equal or not, it compares string's location.

You can click [here](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/) for more information about it.

Comment: yeah that did the job thank you :)
i'm still a little bit new